# I. M. Isaacs Algebra Exercise 9.4

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Recently, I am studying the book [I M Isaacs - Algebra A Graduate Course](https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=GSM/100). I am trying to solve the following exercise:

**(Exercise 9.4)**

Let $P\in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$ and $N={\rm N}_G(P)$. Suppose $z\in {\rm Z}(N)\cap P$ and $z\notin P'$. Show that $z\notin G'$.

HINT: Use the Transfer evaluation lemma. Note that if $tz^nt^{-1}\in P$, then $tz^nt^{-1}=z^n$ by Lemma 9.12.

**Lemma 9.12 (Burnside)**

Let $P\in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$ and suppose that $x,y\in {\rm C}_G(P)$ are conjugate in G. Then $x$ and $y$ are conjugate in $N_G(P)$.

In this problem, it is hard to show that if $tz^nt^{-1}\in P$, then $tz^nt^{-1}=z^n$.

Here is my idea about this question:

By contradiction, suppose that $z\in G'$, then $z\in Z(N)\cap P\cap G'$. In order to use Lemma 9.12，We can choose two elements $tz^nt^{-1}$ and $z^n$，So it suffices to show that $tz^nt^{-1}\in{\rm C}_G(P)$. But I don't know whether it is true or not. Maybe some result about fusion is useful.

Comment: What are $P'$ and $G'$?

Comment: They are $[P,P]$ and $[G,G]$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4577477/fusion-in-the-normaliser-of-a-sylow-subgroup/4577828#4577828